# How to perform thresholding?

Tags: python, image-processing, simpleitk, image-thresholding

When I apply thresholding I'm getting an error:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
img = sitk.ReadImage("Sub1.png")
img=img>20
```

The error is:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-a1d4494dca15> in <module>()
      1 #img = sitk.Image(img.GetSize(), sitk.sitkUInt8)
----> 2 img=img>20

~/sitkpy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/SimpleITK/SimpleITK.py in __gt__(self, other)
   4424            return Greater( self, other )
   4425         try:
-> 4426            return Greater( self, float(other) )
   4427         except (ValueError, TypeError):
   4428            return NotImplemented

~/sitkpy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/SimpleITK/SimpleITK.py in Greater(*args)
  34345 
  34346     """
> 34347     return _SimpleITK.Greater(*args)
  34348 class GridImageSource(ImageFilter_0):
  34349     """

RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK Greater: /tmp/SimpleITK/Code/Common/include/sitkMemberFunctionFactory.hxx:209:
sitk::ERROR: Pixel type: vector of 8-bit unsigned integer is not supported in 2D byN3itk6simple18GreaterImageFilterE
```

I applied `img = sitk.Image(img.GetSize(), sitk.sitkUInt8)` but I'm getting a black image.

Is there any option like `double(img)` or `im2bw` in Python? Will normalize work?
print(img) gives the following

VectorImage (0x2f57af0)   RTTI typeinfo:   itk::VectorImage   Reference Count: 1   Modified Time: 1289   Debug: Off   Object Name:    Observers: 
    none   Source: (none)   Source output name: (none)   Release Data: Off   Data Released: False   Global Release Data: Off   PipelineMTime: 1278   UpdateMTime: 1288   RealTimeStamp: 0 seconds    LargestPossibleRegion: 
    Dimension: 2
    Index: [0, 0]
    Size: [305, 305]   BufferedRegion: 
    Dimension: 2
    Index: [0, 0]
    Size: [305, 305]   RequestedRegion: 
    Dimension: 2
    Index: [0, 0]
    Size: [305, 305]   Spacing: [1, 1]   Origin: [0, 0]   Direction:  1 0 0 1

IndexToPointMatrix:  1 0 0 1

PointToIndexMatrix:  1 0 0 1

Inverse Direction:  1 0 0 1

VectorLength: 4   PixelContainer: 
    ImportImageContainer (0x24ba950)
      RTTI typeinfo:   itk::ImportImageContainer
      Reference Count: 1
      Modified Time: 1285
      Debug: Off
      Object Name: 
      Observers: 
        none
      Pointer: 0x30bb390
      Container manages memory: true
      Size: 372100
      Capacity: 372100

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception reads:

`RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK Greater: /tmp/SimpleITK/Code/Common/include/sitkMemberFunctionFactory.hxx:209:
sitk::ERROR: Pixel type: vector of 8-bit unsigned integer is not supported in 2D byN3itk6simple18GreaterImageFilterE`

Try  running:

`import SimpleITK as sitk
img = sitk.ReadImage("Sub1.png")
print img`

This means that your input image is NOT a scalar image it is an image with multiple components. The ">" or `sitk.GraterThan` does not support vector images. It only support scalar images.

The question is: is your image suppose to be a RGB image? And how do you want to deal with "thresholding" the multi-channel image?

Comment: Actually i saved a nii image into png using itksnap.how to threshold it? i edited the question with print

Comment: can you help me to extract slices from 305*305*39 nii image

Comment: print(img.GetNumberOfComponentsPerPixel())  return 4

Comment: It sound like your mistake was to save a medical image as a png. "help me to extract?" that is a different questions. The edit question with the poorly formatted `print` output indicates the number of components is 4.

Comment: number of components is 4